# vscode open unknown window when i open setting.json file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, settings, vscode-tasks

I'm very confuse about left window in my screen shot when i try to open setting.json file.

do someone know what is this window are and how to hidden them.

[image: screen-shot-setting]

Answer (score 0):

It's the arguments for the flake8 linter, look at like 23 and line 24.
You can try something like

```
"python.linting.flake8Args": [
"--max-line-length=120"
]
```

Comment: no it not this problem i mean the problem is on left window that is unknown where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is this left window is call "default setting" from vscode

can the way to close them is add this setting into setting.json file

or remove it from setting.json file (default is should be false already)

`"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": false,`

but for some reason it set to True in my setting.